# Addition game with timer

Tags: javascript, timer

A count down timer will display 20-s and a "start" button will be visible.

When the start button is pushed:

the "start" will change to "submit"
the timer will count down to 0 over 20 seconds.
the page will display random addition problems (single digit, plus single digit)
a text box will be available to type answers into and when you hit the "submit" button a new random problem will appear
This will repeat until the timer runs out at which time:

The page will display the number of attempted problems, the number of correct problems, and the percentage of correct problems.
The "submit" button will turn back into "start" and the page will be able to run again if you hit start again.

Comment: Please edit the question, adding your current javascript code.

Comment: How about you edit the question and actually make it a question........ You dont have a single question mark in the whole post.

Comment: @victor He is a new user, please explain more kindly

Comment: It's not so much a question as a request for input on this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually have a project I did for my wife/kids for their home schooling to drill their math facts. It doesn't have a count-down but it does time the assessments.

Feel free to check it out here: http://mathfactory.azurewebsites.net/#/

All the front-end code for it is here: http://mathfactory.azurewebsites.net/Client/Bundles/app-bundle.js